# How to make Fluid in width round corner search box using image with IE7 and 8 compatibility?

Tags: css

How to make **Fluid in width** round corner search box using image with IE7 and 8 compatibility?

I need to make like this search box. I know i can make it similar using CSS3, but I need to achieve this for IE to so I will use and image. I have fixed width search box using images but How to achieve when width of search box should be flexible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. oldschool: slice you image into 3 parts. 1. left corner 2. middle part (flexible) 3. right corner. Great article on that topic: [A list Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)
2. use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/), it works great, I use it myself.

Comment: I want to achieve with `input` only

Comment: use the latter then, or use wrapper elements.

Comment: I know CSS3 pie but i want to know if we can achieve that using an images only.

Comment: yes, with slicing and wrapper elements, as I already said. But IMO no need to use images anymore. I wrote a lot of websites, and I never use images, only css and css3pie and msie-filters. This might help, too: http://css3please.com/

Comment: It also could be possible to use js and pseudo-elements :before and :after. Unfortunately it doesnt work with vanilla css.